# Python graphic animation module for a complex time-based problem

Tags: python, animation, graphics, frameworks, libraries

I have a unique problem, and I am presenting the problem graphically. Take a look at the following picture:[image]

In this problem, I have about 50 - 60 globules ( i have named them arbitrarily as ABC, CDE, etc) and they can be grouped under one of the following, at any given time. For example, at Time 1 (left most column) IJK, PQR and JKL have Alkaline property (which i determine based on the several measurements). While MNO, NOP etc. have 'Mildly Alkaline' property, ABC, BCD etc. have 'Neutral' property, EFG, FGH etc have 'Mildly Acidic Property, and finally, HIJ, OPQ etc are 'Acidic in nature. With time (Time 1, Time 2, Time 3 etc, shown as 3 different columns), when I measure their properties again, they may change their property from, say, 'Neutral' to 'Mildly Alkaline' or 'Mildly Alkaline to 'Alkaline' etc.

Case in point, I am showing a couple of examples, which are color coded. For example, At 'Time 1', the globule CDE is 'Neutral', but at time 'Time 2', it has become 'Mildly Alkaline'. Similarly, you can see, XYZ in 'Time 2' has moved from 'Mild Alkaline' to 'Alkaline'. And you can observe regards to VWX from 'Time 2' to 'Time 3'.

Now the problem that I am having at hand, is to graphically capture all these globules something like this, and play like Time 1 -> Time 2 -> Time 3 etc, and see the globules moving 'Up' or 'Down' etc. When I play like a movie, I want to see that CDE is moving Up, while WXY is moving Down. For example, from Time 1 -> Time 2, I should see CDE is animatedly going up, while WXY should be animatedly coming down.

While I have captured all the data, I am finding it challenging to graphically portray this scenario. Any pointers as any libraries to visually analyse these globules moving Up or Down, or staying where ever they are. Any pointers to help me solve this graphical problems, would be much appreciated.

PS: I have used Flask and Streamlit, Plotly, Dash etc. and I have not found anything that can do this kind of a thing. Any pointers, please?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be tedious, but depending on how many time steps are involved, it might be faster for you to just animate this in Powerpoint. Graphing libraries like plotly or matplotlib do have tools to do animations, but may require more work in the short-term.